# HashSet in @Document where entity uses unique ID, DuplicatekeyException

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am using Spring Boot and spring data MongoDB (+mongodb-reactive but I guess that isn't important for this issue). For some auto-generation, I use Lombok.

I have an `User` entity:

```java
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.Indexed;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
...

@Document
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"friends"})
public class User {
  @Id
  String id;

  @Indexed(unique=true)
  String someOtherIdentifier;

  Set<User> friends;

  ....

  public User(String someOtherIdentifier) {
    this.someOtherIdentifier = someOtherIdentifier;
    this.friends = new HashSet<>();
  }

}
```

When I now ran tests where I create two `User` entities after each other, the following exception is thrown:

```
 E11000 duplicate key error collection: managingService.user index: friends.hashedIdentifier dup key: { : null }; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: E11000 duplicate key error collection: managingService.user index: friends.hashedIdentifier dup key: { : null }))
```

The test roughly looks like this (I also get the exception when I test this manually):

```java
    @Test
    void create() {
        User entity = new User("1");
        User newEntity = new User("2");

        StepVerifier.create(repository.save(entity))
                .expectNextMatches(entity::equals)
                .verifyComplete();

        StepVerifier.create(repository.save(newEntity))
                .expectNextMatches(newEntity::equals)
                .verifyComplete();

        StepVerifier.create(repository.count()).expectNext(2L).verifyComplete();
    }
```

I see that the issue get's caused by the `friends`-set, where the second entity has the same `User` within the set. Of course, different users can have the same friend, so in this set, it shouldn't check for unique IDs.
Any help on how to resolve this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe a dumb question but was is the `@Id` package name in imports?

Comment: `import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;`, which seems correct to me

Comment: Maybe you create unique index on field **friends**.

Comment: No, as in the code block above, it ain't annotated to be indexed.

Answer (score 0):

The `@Indexed` annotation is also evaluated against the `Set<User>` resulting in two *unique* indexes.

```
"someOtherIdentifier" : 1
"friends.someOtherIdentifier" : 1
```

Please consider to [disable auto indexes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-usage) and use manual indexes via `IndexOperations` instead.

```java
Index index = new Index("someOtherIdentifier", Direction.ASC).unique();
template.indexOps(User.class).ensureIndex(index);
```